# Why is my largest sub-square-matrix sum program not woring with small matrices with negtive numbers?

Tags: c++, matrix

This program is meant to take in a square matrix of integers and outputs the largest sub-square-matrix sum.
The first line of input is an integer which indicates the dimension of the square matrix, followed by the actual matrix row-by-row.

My program works almost perfectly except it does not work when using small matrices with negative values. Can anyone help me optimise the code, I cant see where its is going wrong

Example Input1:
3

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

Output: 45

Example Input2:
3

1 2 3

4 5 6

-7 -8 -9

Output: 16
NB: Since the largest square matrix is [2 3; 5 6] which sums to 16

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
int  Numberofelements,n,counter = 0,sum=0,result = 0,Maximumvalue = -1, *pointervalue = NULL;

int count = 0;

cin>>n;

int mat[n][n];
int TempMatrix[n][n];


for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
    {
        cin>>mat[i][j];
        if(mat[i][j]<0){
            count++;
        }
    }
}


for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j< n; ++j)
    {
        sum = sum + mat[i][j];
    }
    if (sum > 0 )
    {
        counter++;
    }
    sum = 0;
}

Numberofelements = counter;





for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Numberofelements; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + mat[i][j];
    }

    TempMatrix[0][j] = sum;

    for (int i=1; i<n-Numberofelements+1; i++)
    {
        sum = sum+(mat[i+Numberofelements-1][j] - mat[i-1][j]);

        TempMatrix[i][j] = sum;
    }
}



for (int i=0; i<n-Numberofelements+1; i++)

{
    sum = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < Numberofelements; j++)
    {
        sum  = sum + TempMatrix[i][j];
    }

    if (sum > Maximumvalue)
    {
        Maximumvalue = sum;

        pointervalue = &(mat[i][0]);
    }

    for (int j = 1; j < n-Numberofelements+1; j++)
    {
        sum  = sum + (TempMatrix[i][j+Numberofelements-1] - TempMatrix[i][j-1]);

        if (sum > Maximumvalue)
        {
            Maximumvalue = sum;

            pointervalue = &(mat[i][j]);
        }
    }
}


for (int i = 0; i < Numberofelements; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Numberofelements; j++)
    {
        result+=*(pointervalue + i*n + j);
    }
}

cout << result;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int mat[n][n];int TempMatrix[n][n];` -- This is not legal C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a constant expression, not a variable.  Instead use `std::vector`.  Also, if you have a test case that fails, please hard-code those values into your program.  There is no need for `cin` statements.

Comment: And also, because it is not legal C++, this: `pointervalue = &(mat[i][j]);` does not necessarily mean you are pointing to a contiguous memory block, where you can now just index into the 2D array using pointer arithmetic.  If it were a true 2D array, then that is a different story, but it isn't a true 2D array.